# How can i use a stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have the following five tables:

[image]

I need to implement a stored procedure such that `execute sp_getStandingUpToDate (aDate)` computes and shows the standings table, same as in the following figure:

[image]

up to the date aDate.

I need to call with any invalid date, resulting in an error with a message “Invalid date!” All transactions that have been done will be rolled back and stopped doing further operations.

How can I create this?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Show us your code attempt, and perhaps you'll get some advices!

Comment: First of all you should avoid the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix Second, this scream of homework and shows no effort on your part. We don't like to do homework and we really like to see people post what they have tried. Last but not least, even if we did want to help we need some details other than just pictures. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: i already know. i want to get advices about starting

Comment: Look like you just need to aggregate by game with a simple `group by` on the goals table joined to matches so you can filter by date. You'll use `case` to determine wins/ties/losses, etc. Then you wrap that query with an outer query to sum everything up by team. Looks like two of the tables aren't needed here.

Comment: Actually I guess you do need those two tables in order to determine which side scored the goals. That's probably a dumb design with the whole purpose of making your problem a little harder.

Comment: thank you so much let me try this

Comment: Well the GF and GA is another snag... Let me think about that.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably as a SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement, and using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

I probably shouldn't encourage you to post this kind of question. There's the presumed lack of attempt and all that's already been mentioned. And then you've failed to fully describe the problem: not everybody is going to know what GF, GA, GD are and how to calculate points.

So here is what I believe to be a working answer. If you turn it in as is then your teacher will probably know that you didn't write it. But I suspect that if you manage to tear it apart and rewrite it then you'll have learned something in the process. So at the risk of being downvoted here it is:

```
with matchSummary as (
    select
        t.teamID,
        min(t.name) as teamName,
        sum(case when pt.teamID = t.teamID then 1 else 0 end) as GF,
        sum(case when pt.teamID = t.teamID then 0 else 1 end) as GA
    from
        team t
        inner join match m on t.teamID in (m.homeTeamID, m.visitingTeamID)
        inner join goals g on g.matchID = m.matchID
        inner join player_team pt on pt.playerID = g.playerID
    where m.dateOfMatch < @aDate
    group by m.matchID, t.teamID
)
select
    /* GD is first tie-breaker. Are there others? */
    row_number() over (
        order by
            sum(case when GF > GA then 3 when GF = GA then 1 end) desc,
            sum(GF) - sum(GA) desc
    ) as Pos,
    min(teamName) as "Team Name",
    count(*) as GP,
    count(case when GF > GA then 1 end) as W,
    count(case when GF = GA then 1 end) as T,
    count(case when GF < GA then 1 end) as L,
    sum(GF) as GF,
    sum(GA) as GA,
    sum(GF) - sum(GA) as GD,
    sum(case when GF > GA then 3 when GF = GA then 1 end) as Pts
from matchSummary
group by teamID;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
select distinct t.name as TeamName,count(*) GP
from team t,match m,match m2
where t.teamID=m.homeTeamID and t.teamID=m2.visitingTeamID 
group by m.matchID,t.name
```

This code gives me the number of match a team played,
though I get 17 instead of 34.

Comment: Never suggest using SQL antipatterns like implicit joins. These were replaced over 20 years ago, it is time to start using the code that is best for this century!